# Endless Permutation and RAM

Tags: python, list, data-science

I have a list with around 1500 number (1 to 1500) and I want to get all the possible Permutation out of it to do some calculations and choose the smallest number out of all of it.

Problem is that the number of possibilites as you can figure is wayyy wayyy too big and my computer just freeze whiel running the code so I have to make a forced restart. Also my RAM is 8GB so it should be big enough (?) or so I hope.

To limit it I can specify a start point but that won't reduce it much.

Also it's a super important thing but I feel so lost. what do you think should I do to make it run ?

Comment: Check out the algorithm for generating permutations in order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

Comment: What **exactly** are you doing? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What calculations are you doing with the permutations?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have a net of locations with each location have it coordinate points. I have in total around 1500 location. In each point there's like a timed alarm and I need to find the shortest order to go through all the points and trying to dis-activate as much alarms as possible. (( 1 out of 2 ))

Comment: -Therefor I need to calculate first the distance between each point in one permutation using Euclidean then I calculate arrival time which is the total of distances between points ( 1 m =1 min )  and at the end I calculate my goal which is the delay : arrivaltime-alarmtime between each point, I add it all together to get the total delay which should be as small as possible which is why I don't want to miss any permutation. (( 2 out of 2 ))

Comment: @sparkle That's the classic [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). There are much more efficient algorithms for this problem than using brute force by iterating through all permutations.

Comment: @blhsing I never knew it was such a classic problem ! many many thanks for drawing my attention to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of generators and itertools saves memory a lot. Generators are just like lists with an exception that new elements generated one by one rather than stored in memory. Even if your problem has a better solution, mastering the generator will help you to save memory in future.

Note in Python 3 `map` is already a generator (while for Python 2 use `imap` instead of `map`)

```
import itertools


array = [ 1, 2, ... , 1500] # or other numbers
f = sum   # or whatever function you have


def fmax_on_perms(array, f): 
    perms = itertools.permutations(array) # generator of all the 
           permutations rather than static list
    fvalues = map(my_function, perms) # generator of values of your   function on different permutations
    return max(fvalues)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ! this solved the problem somehow when I tried it but I found a better understanding of the problem when I read about the TSM problem.